# How to remove the first charcter of nnumber in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove the first charcter of my numbers, but I'm not sure why it's not working. After executing my code I want to have these numbers:

3032659875

3032369875

5456663323

3265333333

3032659898

Any help please?? Thanks a lot!

Here's my code:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td class = "usersPhoneNumber">13032659875</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class = "usersPhoneNumber">13032369875</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class = "usersPhoneNumber">15456663323</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class = "usersPhoneNumber">13265333333</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class = "usersPhoneNumber">13032659898</td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
            var theNumber = $(".usersPhoneNumber");
            if ((theNumber.text()).length === 11) {
                var val = $(this).html();
                $(this).html(val.substring(1, val.length));
            }
    });
```

**Live Demo**
https://jsfiddle.net/henrygranados/mLar8bja/

Comment: What is `$(this)` in your code supposed to be? Did you mean to put that code in a `.each()` loop that processes each phone number?

Comment: I added a console.log statement to start you on your way to uncovering this issue. Check out your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mLar8bja/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `.usersPhoneNumber` are multiple elements so you need to loop trough them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // loop over your elements
  $(".usersPhoneNumber").each(function() {
    // check if elements length is 11
    if ($(this).text().length === 11) {
      var val = $(this).html();
      $(this).html(val.substring(1, val.length));
      console.log("tes33");
      alert("testing");
    }
  })
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/putvande/mLar8bja/6/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet:

```
$(".usersPhoneNumber").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().length === 11) $(this).html($(this).html().substr(1))
})
```

```js
$(".usersPhoneNumber").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().length === 11) $(this).html($(this).html().substr(1))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="usersPhoneNumber">13032659875</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="usersPhoneNumber">13032369875</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="usersPhoneNumber">15456663323</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="usersPhoneNumber">13265333333</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="usersPhoneNumber">13032659898</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bro!! voting your answer up!

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the elements. If you give the `.text()` method a function argument, it will do the loop automatically -- the returned value of the function replaces the element's text.

```js
$(".usersPhoneNumber").text(function(i, oldtext) {
  if (oldtext.length == 11) {
    return oldtext.substr(1);
  } else {
    return oldtext;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="usersPhoneNumber">13032659875</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="usersPhoneNumber">13032369875</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="usersPhoneNumber">15456663323</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="usersPhoneNumber">13265333333</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="usersPhoneNumber">13032659898</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I see that you're always there to help others and that is awesome!. Keep up the programming spirit :)!. I'm voting your answer up for that cause mate!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
            var xx = $(".usersPhoneNumber");
            //alert(xx.text());
           $(".usersPhoneNumber").each(function(){

              var phno = $(this).text();
              //alert(phno);
              if (phno.length === 11) {
                var val = $(this).html();                   
                $(this).html(val.substring(1, val.length));              
            }


           });
 });
```

I have updated your code. Check this out. It is working.
The problem with your code is, you are not looping through each of the numbers.Your variable, "theNumber" is an object.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use jquery "each"

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
                var xx = $(".usersPhoneNumber");
                $(xx).each(function(){
                    var val = $(this).html();
                    $(this).html(val.substring(1, val.length));
                    console.log("tes33");
                    alert("testing");
```

[updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLar8bja/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution:

```
var xx = $(".usersPhoneNumber");

for(var i=0; i<xx.length;i++){
    xx[i].innerHTML = xx[i].innerHTML.substring(
        xx[i].innerHTML.length - (xx[i].innerHTML.length-1))
    console.log(xx[i].innerHTML);
}
```